# How to disable inline p:calendar (primefaces)

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I've noticed that disabling an inline p:calendar actually hides it.

I've been expecting that a disabled p:calendar would be just a calendar being shown but read-only, just as all other typical JSF components.

If I wanted a hidden p:calendar, I'd use the rendered attribute.

Is there any way to disable an inline p:calendar without hiding it? (just blocking mouse and keyboards for it)

Primefaces 4.

Answer (score 2):

After all the outcome is a span, so you could use normal jQuery to adjust the styling.

```
$('.disabledCalendar').children().fadeTo('slow', .7);
$('.disabledCalendar').append('<div style="position: absolute;top:0;left:0;width: 100%;height:100%;z-index:2;opacity:0.4;filter: alpha(opacity = 50)"></div>');
$(".ui-datepicker-inline td").unbind();
```

And assign the class to the calendar:

```
<p:calendar styleClass="disabledCalendar" mode="inline" />
```

**Note:** this can be tricky, if someone played with the styling on the client-side, and remove the mask. They would be able to change the value, since this solution apparently doesn't reflect on the server-side. I would put some validation on the server-side that the value didn't change.

**Edit:**
you can also combine my solution with **Kishor P** answer and unbind the events (I have edited the code of the jQuery).
this way it would be more secure.

A small working example can be found on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/calendar/main.xhtml). And an [online Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/calendar/main.xhtml).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works fine..Chokran :)

Answer (score 1):

I used `readonly=true` attribute, but it didn't worked for me.

One more attribute is `readonlyInput=true` but this is for not Inline calendar.

So Finally I ended up unbinding all the events attached to `<TD>` of  `p:calendar` component through JQuery.

I don't know if its a feasible solution(there may be other alternatives) but this script works just fine.

```
$(document).ready(
    function makeCalendarReadOnly(){
        $(".ui-datepicker-inline td").unbind();
    }
);
```